# Data is not inserting into mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to insert form value into database, but the data is not going into mysql. I spent lots of hour but could not resolve it...
this is my code:

```
$query = "insert into $tabl (userid, username, question,  board, class, subject, article, status, uniq_id,date,activation  ) values('$userid', '$username', '$question', '$board', '$class', '$subject', '$article', 'unread', '$uniq',CURDATE(), '0')";
$row = mysql_query($query);

if($row)
{
     header("location:ask-questions.php?msg=saved");
}
else
{
    header("location:ask-questions.php?msg=not been saved");
}
//////////   (1)End of the Code /////////////
?>
```

all things are ok, and i `echo $sql,` this also working fine...
any help would be appreciate....

Comment: try `$row = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());` Also check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php why you shouldnt use mysql

Comment: one of your values could contain a single quote `'` which can cause the query to fail. use `mysql_real_escape_string($val)` before inserting

Comment: y downvote..................?

Comment: Check your field type i.e. data type if it is date then insert the date in the proper format. also change table field name from date to some thing else or put it in backtick ``in your query

Comment: echo the `$sql` and run it directly on the db, if it works it means you have a connection error, if it doesn't it means you have a syntax error or missing table/field in the query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`date` is reserved word in `mysql`. use backtick `` ` `` around that kind of reserved words when used as column name.

```
 $query = "insert into $tabl (userid, username, question,  
 board, class, subject, article, status, uniq_id, `date`,activation  ) 
 values('$userid', '$username', '$question', '$board', '$class', '$subject', '$article', 'unread', '$uniq',CURDATE(), '0')";

 $row = mysql_query($query) OR die(mysql_error());
```

Also stop using `mysql_*` functions, they are deprecated. Start `mysqli` OR `PDO`.

Comment: Not true, `date` is not a reserved word in MySQL. Because of so many people using `date` as a field name, the developers removed it as a reserved word. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html

Comment: okkk, but still not inserting into database, $sql carry data but i dont know y the data not going into table

Comment: @Tracy put `$row = mysql_query($query) OR die(mysql_error());` for checking the error. Is `$tabl` defined anywhere.

Comment: ya...thats all okk, ok i m rying ur code...wait,  n y people downvoting my question

Comment: @Tracy I think they are downvoting because you are deprecated `mysql_*` functions.

Comment: okk, in future i'll try to use mysqli_*, n thanks yogesh i found my error... :)

Comment: a field name cousing problem n i fixed that, n now data is going into mysql, yogesh where can i learn to use mysqli_* function

Comment: @Tracy It's official site http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php It is same as `mysql_*`.